# $ \operatorname{Hom}_{D(\mathcal{A})}(B, H^n(A^{\bullet}) ) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{D(\mathcal{A})}(B,A^{\bullet}[n] ) $ injective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian
category of finite homological dimension and $D^b(\mathcal{A})$ the associated derived category
of bounded compexes. Let $A^{\bullet} \in D^b(\mathcal{A})$ and $n$ minimal such that $A^n \neq 0$. Thus $A^{\bullet}$ is of the form

$$ ... \to 0 \to A^n \to A^{n+1} \to ...   $$

We obtain an obvious inclusion $H^n(A^{\bullet}) \subset A^{\bullet}[n]$ where as usually we consider $H^n(A^{\bullet}) $ as a chain complex with only nonzero entry $H^n(A^{\bullet}) $ in degree $0$.

Let $B \in \mathcal{A}$ arbitrary which we can like $H^n(A^{\bullet}) $ regard also as a chain complex with only nonzero entry $B $ in degree $0$.
*Question:* Why is the canonical map

$$ \operatorname{Hom}_{D(\mathcal{A})}(B, H^n(A^{\bullet}) ) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{D(\mathcal{A})}(B,A^{\bullet}[n] )     $$

induced by
$H^n(A^{\bullet}) \subset A^{\bullet}[n]$ *injective*?

note that we consider morphims in $D(\mathcal{A})$ and not in the category of complexes in $\mathcal{A}$, where the statement would become trivial. I found this statement as part of the proof of Proposition 2.73 in Huybrecht's Fourier-Mukai Transformations in Algebraic Geometry on page 60.

outlook: does it hold in more general setting like if $X^{\bullet}, Y^{\bullet} $ and $Z^{\bullet}$ are complexes in  $\mathcal{A}$ and there is an inclusion $X^{\bullet} \subset Y^{\bullet} $, then

$$ \operatorname{Hom}_{D(\mathcal{A})}(Z^{\bullet}, X^{\bullet}) ) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{D(\mathcal{A})}(Z^{\bullet},Y^{\bullet} )     $$

is an injection? I think that in such general setting the statement not holds since the morphisms in $D(\mathcal{A})$ differ stongly from morphisms in the category of complexes in $\mathcal{A}$, but I haven't a conterexample. Presumably a homotopy might kill a nontrivial class in $ \operatorname{Hom}_{D(\mathcal{A})}(Z^{\bullet}, X^{\bullet}) ) $ after passing to $ \operatorname{Hom}_{D(\mathcal{A})}(Z^{\bullet},Y^{\bullet} )     $. Even worse when we pass to the equivalence classes of roofs in $D(\mathcal{A})$, what is really hard to control.
Nevertheless, what's the reason why the above injectivity holds for original problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, replacing $A$ by $A[n]$ we can and will assume $n = 0$.
Then we have a distinguished triangle
$$
H^0(A) \to A \to \tau^{\ge 1}(A),
$$
where $\tau^{\ge 1}$ is the canonical truncation functor, so that $H^i(\tau^{\ge 1}(A)) = 0$ for $i \le 0$. Applying the functor $\mathrm{Hom}(B,-)$ to this triangle we obtain an exact sequence
$$
\dots \to 
\mathrm{Hom}(B,\tau^{\ge 1}(A)[-1]) \to 
\mathrm{Hom}(B,H^0(A)) \to 
\mathrm{Hom}(B,A) \to \dots,
$$
so it is enough to show
$$
\mathrm{Hom}(B,\tau^{\ge 1}(A)[-1]) = 0.
$$

This fact follows from the standard properties of t-structures, but if you want you can prove it in a similar way.
First, write a similar triangle
$$
H^1(A)[-1] \to \tau^{\ge 1}(A) \to \tau^{\ge 2}(A),
$$
apply $\mathrm{Hom}(B,-)$ and reduced the claim to $\mathrm{Hom}(B,\tau^{\ge 2}(A)[-2]) = 0$. Then do this again and again, and using the boundedness, finally prove this.

Comment: thank you for your answer. two remarks: , firstly 
I guess that in your 
penultimate sentence you wanted to say "... and reduce
the claim to $\mathrm{Hom}(B,\tau^{\ge 2}(A)[-1]) = 0$ (!), and not
$\mathrm{Hom}(B,\tau^{\ge 1}(A)[-2]) = 0$, because otherwise
I not know how I want to exploit induction hypothesis, right?

Comment: secondly, why the sequence
$H^0(A) \to A \to \tau^{\ge 1}(A)$ is a distinguished 
triangle? note that by definition the distinguished
triangles are isomorphic to sequences of shape

$A \xrightarrow{f} B \to C(f)$ with cone $C(f)$. as 
$C(f)^n = A^{n+1} \oplus B_n$, in our case the
cone of $H^0(A) \xrightarrow{i} A$ is given 
by $C(i)^n= A^n = (\tau^{\ge 1})^n$ for $n \ge 1$, 
$C(i)^0=A^0, C(i)^{-1}= H^0(A)$ and $C(i)^m=0$ else
for $m \le -2$.

Comment: and the most natural idea came into my mind 
is to show that as you claimed $H^0(A) \to A \to \tau^{\ge 1}(A)$
is a distinguished triangle, is to show that 
$C(i)$ and $\tau^{\ge 1}$ are homotopy equivalent. but 
even that's not clear. 

one of the tasks is to find a map $\eta$ with
$\eta_n: C(i)^n \to C(i)^{n-1}$ such that 
in every degree $id_{C(i)^n}= d \circ \eta_n + \eta_{n+1} \circ d$ holds.
how then should the map $\eta_0: A_0 \to C(i)^{-1}= H^0(A)$
be defined?

Comment: we know only that $H^0(A) := ker(d_0) \subset A_0$.
furthermore $\eta_{-1}=0$ since $C(i)^{-2}=0$, so
we cannot take a "cheap trick" by setting $\eta_0:=0$, since
we need for the homotopy the condition $id_{H^0(A)}= 
d \circ \eta_{-1}+\eta_0 \circ d$. but possibly
my approach is simply a wrong one.

Comment: How do you see that 
$H^0(A) \to A \to \tau^{\ge 1}(A)$ is a distinguished 
triangle?

Comment: @user7391733: You are right, there was a typo, I corrected it now. As for the triangle, note that everything is considered as objects of derived category, i.e., up to quasi-isomorphism. The triangle comes from the canonical truncation triangle $$\tau^{\le 0}(A) \to A \to \tau^{\ge 1}(A)$$ and an observation that $\tau^{\le 0}(A)$ has only one cohomology $H^0(A)$, hence quasiisomorphic to it.

Comment: yes I see, thank you! I have completely forgotten 
that for a trunification $\tau^{\le m}(A)$ the 
$m$-th degree entry should be kernel of
$d^n: A^m \to A^{m+1}$ and not simply $A^m$. That's
what confused me before. So in our case above
$\tau^{\le 0}(A)$ has indeed only one nonzero entry,
namely as you said $H^0(A)$ in degree $0$, and that's
also it's own cohomology.